# Upgrade SQLite Database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a quote application which has a SQLite database called successquotes in its assets folder.

I loaded some data in successquotes(sqllite local database in assets) when I launched the application.
Now I added some more data in the database.
But when I try to update the application it's not showing the extra data which I recently added in the localdatabase.

what should I do to show the new updated data?
My databasehelper class is like below.

Can anybody please suggest me what changes I need to do?

```
public class DataBaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // The Android's default system path of your application database.
    private static String DB_PATH;

    private static String DB_NAME = "SuccessQuotes";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

    private final Context myContext;


    /**
     * Constructor Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to
     * access to the application assets and resources.
     * 
     * @param context
     */
    public DataBaseHandler(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
        DB_PATH = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).toString();
        Log.e("path", DB_PATH);
    }

    // ==============================================================================

    /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
     * database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if (dbExist) {
            // do nothing - database already exist
        } else {

            // By calling this method and empty database will be created into
            // the default system path
            // of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that
            // database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }

    // ==============================================================================

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
     * time you open the application.
     * 
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase() {

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {

            // database does't exist yet.

        }

        if (checkDB != null) {

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    // ==============================================================================

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
     * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
     * handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH;

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    // ==============================================================================

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

        // Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    // ==============================================================================

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

    }

    // ==============================================================================

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    // ==============================================================================

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){



    }
}
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking for here. Could you edit your question to be more specific about what your question is?

Comment: Thanks. I have edited it :)

Comment: Are you updating the DB version?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use BroadcastReceiver.
Once your database is changed/filled with new data, you can send a broadcast event from your database handler:

```
Intent localIntent = new Intent();
localIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
localIntent.setAction("some_action_string");
```

And in the activity you want to get notified, you register a BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class DatabaseUpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //do your update here
        }
    }
```

And in your activity (in onCreate) register this broadcast receiver to receive the updates sent from your database handler:

```
DatabaseUpdateReceiver receiver = new DatabaseUpdateReceiver();
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("some_action_string");
intentFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
registerReceiver(receiver , intentFilter);
```